# Extract number or string after string in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have several 1.000 URLs and want to extract some values from the URL parameters.
Here some examples from the DB:

["www.xxx.com?uci=6666&rci=fefw"] 
["www.xxx.com?uci=61
["www.xxx.com?rci=62&uci=5536"] 
["www.xxx.com?uci=6666&utm_source=XXX"] 
["www.xxx.com?pccst=TEST%20sTESTg"]
["www.xxx.com?pccst=TEST2%20s&uci=1"]
["www.xxx.com?uci=1pccst=TEST42rt24&rci=2"]

How can I extract the value of the parameter UCI. It is always a digit number (don’t know the exact length).
I tried it with REGEXP_EXTRACT. But I didn't succeed:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(URL, '(uci)\=[0-9]+') AS UCI_extract
```

And I also want to extract the value of the parameter pccst. It can be every character and I don`t know the exact length. But it always ends with “ or ? or &

I tried it also with REGEXP_EXTRACT but didn't succeed:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(URL, r'pccst\=(.*)(\"|\&|\?)') AS pccst_extract
```

I am really not the REGEX expert. 
So would be great if someone could help me.
Thanks a lot in advance,
Peter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adapt [this](https://www.pascallandau.com/bigquery-snippets/extract-url-parameters-array/) solution

```
#standardSQL
# Extract query parameters from a URL as ARRAY in BigQuery; standard-sql; 2018-04-08
# @see http://www.pascallandau.com/bigquery-snippets/extract-url-parameters-array/
WITH examples AS (
  SELECT 1   AS id, 'www.xxx.com?uci=6666&rci=fefw' AS query 
  UNION ALL SELECT 2, 'www.xxx.com?uci=1pccst%20TEST42rt24&rci=2'
  UNION ALL SELECT 3, 'www.xxx.com?pccst=TEST2%20s&uci=1'
)
SELECT 
  id, 
  query,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(query,r'(?:\?|&)((?:[^=]+)=(?:[^&]*))') as params,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(query,r'(?:\?|&)(?:([^=]+)=(?:[^&]*))') as keys,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(query,r'(?:\?|&)(?:(?:[^=]+)=([^&]*))') as values
FROM examples
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. To extract all query parameters from a URL as ARRAY is perfect!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Below example for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT "www.xxx.com?uci=6666&rci=fefw" url UNION ALL
  SELECT "www.xxx.com?uci=61" UNION ALL
  SELECT "www.xxx.com?rci=62&uci=5536" UNION ALL
  SELECT "www.xxx.com?uci=6666&utm_source=XXX" UNION ALL
  SELECT "www.xxx.com?pccst=TEST%20sTESTg" UNION ALL
  SELECT "www.xxx.com?pccst=TEST2%20s&uci=1" UNION ALL
  SELECT "www.xxx.com?uci=1&pccst=TEST42rt24&rci=2" 
)
SELECT 
  url, 
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(url, r'[?&]uci=(.*?)(?:$|&)') uci,
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(url, r'[?&]pccst=(.*?)(?:$|&)') pccst
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

result is

```
Row url                                         uci     pccst    
1   www.xxx.com?pccst=TEST%20sTESTg             null    TEST%20sTESTg    
2   www.xxx.com?pccst=TEST2%20s&uci=1           1       TEST2%20s    
3   www.xxx.com?uci=1&pccst=TEST42rt24&rci=2    1       TEST42rt24   
4   www.xxx.com?uci=61                          61      null     
5   www.xxx.com?rci=62&uci=5536                 5536    null     
6   www.xxx.com?uci=6666&rci=fefw               6666    null     
7   www.xxx.com?uci=6666&utm_source=XXX         6666    null
```

Also, below option to parse out all key-value pairs so, then you can dynamically select needed

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT "www.xxx.com?uci=6666&rci=fefw" url UNION ALL
  SELECT "www.xxx.com?uci=61" UNION ALL
  SELECT "www.xxx.com?rci=62&uci=5536" UNION ALL
  SELECT "www.xxx.com?uci=6666&utm_source=XXX" UNION ALL
  SELECT "www.xxx.com?pccst=TEST%20sTESTg" UNION ALL
  SELECT "www.xxx.com?pccst=TEST2%20s&uci=1" UNION ALL
  SELECT "www.xxx.com?uci=1pccst=TEST42rt24&rci=2" 
)
SELECT url, 
  ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT 
      SPLIT(kv, '=')[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] key, 
      SPLIT(kv, '=')[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] value 
    FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(SUBSTR(url, LENGTH(NET.HOST(url)) + 2), '&')) kv
  ) key_value_pair
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```